# Service-worker not intercepting first fetch call on initial load

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm having an issue with my custom service-worker. It doesn't seem to be intercepting the first fetch req when the page is initially loaded (but all fetch reqs afterwards are intercepted correctly). However, if I reload the page, all fetch reqs are intercepted correctly by the service-worker. So the problem only exists on initial load of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "first-load" behavior is by design.  ServiceWorkers can't intercept the initial requests until they enter the `installing` state and end with the `activated` state.  One option is to first show users an "Installing..." page, wait for the SW to become active, and then refresh the page. The SW can then serve an "SW activated" page.  See example: https://fetch-progress.anthum.com/sw-basic/ - [`sw-simple.js`](https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators/blob/master/sw-basic/sw-simple.js#L13-L17)

```
// INTERCEPT:  /, /index.html, /index.htm 
if ([scope, scope + 'index.html', scope + 'index.htm'].includes(event.request.url)) {
  event.respondWith(fetch(scope + 'sw-installed.html'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you want to do this:

> The default is consistency, if your page loads without a service worker, neither will its subresources.

https://web.dev/articles/service-worker-lifecycle#activate

If you want to continue:

> The following example uses `claim()` inside service worker's "`activate`" event listener so that clients loaded in the same scope do not need to be reloaded before their fetches will go through this service worker.

```js
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(clients.claim());
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim

Note that this affects *all* clients of the activated service worker, which may be undesirable in some situations (e.g. a new service worker may become active for a page that was loaded using an older service worker.) AFAIK it isn't possible to claim just one specific client - you gotta claim them all.